# Sum of products of pairs in a list

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, python-itertools

This is the problem I have. Given a list

```
xList = [9, 13, 10, 5, 3]
```

I would like to calculate for sum of each element multiplied by subsequent elements

```
sum([9*13, 9*10, 9*5 , 9*3]) + 
sum([13*10, 13*5, 13*3]) + 
sum([10*5, 10*3]) + 
sum ([5*3])
```

in this case the answer is **608**.

Is there a way to do this perhaps with `itertools` or natively with `numpy`?

Below is a function I came up with. It does the job but it is far from ideal as I would like to add other stuff as well.

```
    def SumProduct(xList):
        ''' compute the sum of the product 
        of a list 
        e.g. 
        xList = [9, 13, 10, 5, 3]
        the result will be 
        sum([9*13, 9*10, 9*5 , 9*3]) + 
        sum([13*10, 13*5, 13*3]) + 
        sum([10*5, 10*3]) + 
        sum ([5*3])
        '''
        xSum = 0
        for xnr, x in enumerate(xList):
            #print xnr, x
            xList_1 = np.array(xList[xnr+1:])
            #print x * xList_1
            xSum = xSum + sum(x * xList_1)
        return xSum
```

Any help appreciated.

N.B: In case you wonder, I am trying to implement [Krippendorf's alpha](http://repository.upenn.edu/cgi/viewcontent.cgi?article=1043&context=asc_papers) with **pandas**

Comment: Personal curiosity (looked at the literature), what are the benefits of using this realibility over the more popular ones?

Comment: actually, this measures generalized most others see 
http://www.afhayes.com/public/cmm2007.pdf and http://www.agreestat.com/book4/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
In [14]: x = [9, 13, 10, 5, 3]

In [15]: np.triu(np.outer(x, x), k=1).sum()
Out[15]: 608
```

but I'd go with @user2357112's answer.

Answer (score 26):

```
x = array([9, 13, 10, 5, 3])
result = (x.sum()**2 - x.dot(x)) / 2
```

This takes advantage of some mathematical simplifications to work in linear time and constant space, compared to other solutions that might have quadratic performance.

Here's a diagram of how this works. Suppose `x = array([2, 3, 1])`. Then if you view the products as the areas of rectangles:

```
x is this stick: -- --- -

x.sum()**2 is this rectangle:
   -- --- -
  |xx xxx x
  |xx xxx x

  |xx xxx x
  |xx xxx x
  |xx xxx x

  |xx xxx x

x.dot(x) is this diagonal bit:
   -- --- -
  |xx
  |xx

  |   xxx
  |   xxx
  |   xxx

  |       x

(x.sum()**2 - x.dot(x)) is the non-diagonal parts:
   -- --- -
  |   xxx x
  |   xxx x

  |xx     x
  |xx     x
  |xx     x

  |xx xxx

and (x.sum()**2 - x.dot(x)) / 2 is the product you want:
   -- --- -
  |   xxx x
  |   xxx x

  |       x
  |       x
  |       x

  |
```

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser: Whoops. Fixed.

Comment: Holy bejezes. Math is pretty useful sometimes, huh?

Comment: beats itertools by a mile, can you explain how it works?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham: I tried to make some ASCII-art diagrams. Do they help?

Comment: Another way to see why this works: Start with the square of the sum, say (a+b+c+d)^2. This expands to have a whole bunch of terms (put it into WolframAlpha to see). We want all the terms except the ones that just have the elements squared, so those need to be subtracted. The remaining terms are all multiplied by 2, so divide by that and we're left with what we want.

Comment: thanks. this actually explains my problem in more broad  terms.

Comment: This is so magical.... the vision.... I have to admit the ASCII art didn't really help, but the explanation of @itzy did it.

Answer (score 8):

You actually want combinations not product:

```
from itertools import combinations

print(sum(a*b for a,b in combinations(xList,2)))
608
```

Even creating a numpy array from a python list, [@user2357112](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30039414/2141635)  answer wipes the floor with the rest of us.

```
In [38]: timeit sum(a*b for a,b in combinations(xlist,2))
10000 loops, best of 3:
89.7 µs per loop

In [40]: timeit sum(mul(*t) for t in itertools.combinations(xlist, 2))
1000 loops, best of 3:
165 µs per loop

In [41]: %%timeit                                        
x = array(arr)
(x.sum()**2 - (x**2).sum()) / 2
   ....: 
100000 loops, best of 3:
 10.9 µs per loop

In [42]: timeit np.triu(np.outer(x, x), k=1).sum()
10000 loops, best of 3:
48.1 µs per loop
In [59]: %%timeit
....: xarr = np.array(xList)
....: N = xarr.size
....: range1 = np.arange(N)
....: mask = range1[:,None] < range1
....: out = ((mask*xarr)*xarr[:,None]).sum()
10000 loops, best of 3: 30.4 µs per loop
```

All the lists/arrays had 50 elements.

Stealing the logic from user2357112 and using it on a normal list with sum  python is pretty darn efficient:

```
In [63]: timeit result = (sum(xList)**2 - sum(x ** 2 for x in xList)) / 2
100000 loops, best of 3: 
4.63 µs per loop
```

But for a large array the numpy solution is still significantly faster.

Answer (score 4):

It looks like you want to get every combination of two elements (pairs) in that list, compute the product of each pair, and sum over these products:

```
import itertools

xlist = [9, 13, 10, 5, 3]
pairs = itertools.combinations(xlist, 2)
answer = 0
for pair in pairs:
    answer += pair[0] * pair[1]
```

The one-liner to do this:

```
import itertools
import operator

sum(operator.mul(*t) for t in itertools.combinations(xlist, 2))
```

Comment: thank you. The itertools.combinations is what I was lacking. I went for the user2357112 answer as it explains the issue more generally.

Answer (score 1):

One approach -

```
xarr = np.array(xList)

N = xarr.size
range1 = np.arange(N)

mask = range1[:,None] < range1
out = ((mask*xarr)*xarr[:,None]).sum()
```

Another one -

```
xarr = np.array(xList)

N = xarr.size
range1 = np.arange(N)

R,C = np.where(range1[:,None] < range1)
out = (xarr[R]*xarr[C]).sum()
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are interested in doing this by hand (without help from the stdlib):

```
def combinations(L):
    for i,elem in enumerate(L):
        for e in L[i+1:]:
            yield (elem, e)

def main(xlist):
    answer = 0
    for a,b in combinations(xlist):
        answer += a*b
    return answer
```

Comment: Why wouldn't you use the standard library?

Comment: Some times, people are interested in the algorithm that solves the problem, more than the quick one-liner. That is exactly why I both prefaced my answer with "if you are interested in doing this by hand", and added [a more pythonic answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30039432/198633)

Comment: The question explicitly asked for a solution using `itertools` or `numpy`.

Comment: @chepner: I have already added such an answer. However, a future user may still be interested in this answer, even if OP isn't. This is exactly why I posted this solution as a separate answer

Comment: @chepner: ehh, "perhaps with" isn't strong enough to rule out other answers, IMHO.